# adding hours to date and time in php gives wrong output

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
$datetime = Carbon::now()
$datetime = date($datetime);
$date = strtotime($datetime);
$date = strtotime($datetime);$dispatchDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime("+2 hours", $date));
```

Is this correct.. actully i am gettig wrong output. for any time it just give time like 2016-07-13 14:07:43 or 2016-07-13 13:07:43 time

Comment: what output you want ??

Comment: What is the expected output? What isn't working? As your question stands now it's unclear what the issue is

Comment: in this date i want to add 2 hours.
for example date and time is: 2016-07-13 12:29:00 then output should be 2016-07-13 14:29:00

Comment: change `+2 hours` to `7200`.

Comment: you should probably work with Datetime: http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.add.php

Comment: @claudios still its gives me wrong output

Comment: @AmolRokade, check out the answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$twoHoursLater = $date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('+2 hours'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `carbon` why not utilizing it to get what you want to achieve. Notice that I added the `addHours()` function here.
Try the code below and learn from it.

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2012, 1, 31, 0);

echo $dt->toDateTimeString();

echo $dt->addHours(24);
echo $dt->addHour();
```